# Google Assistant Plugin Options On Android Studio (Hedgehog)

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, google-assistant, app-actions

I realize this isn't exactly a programming question, but I can't find an answer anywhere. I'm having trouble with Android Studio and plugins.

I've been trying to implement shortcuts with custom intents in my app, but I'm having a very difficult time testing them.  All I have been able to manage is to upload and test through an internal-testing track on the Playstore.

The App Actions Test Tool plugin google docs discusses is both depreciated and requires a plugin, com.google.gtc.login, that cannot be found in the Marketplace.  I presume the missing plugin is not supported on Android Studio (Hedgehog).

The Google Assistant Plugin is the replacement for the App Actions Test Tool plugin.  It can't be found in the Marketplace and must be directly downloaded from JetBrains (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16739-google-assistant).  However, the highest version only supports up to Android Studio (Giraffe).

Are there any options for testing app actions in Android Studio (Hedgehog)?  Do I need to go down to a lower version in order to test app actions?  Am I stuck with uploading internal-testing releases and waiting for updates?

Comment: I am in the same boat. I'm interested in adding this feature but it's a little worrying that Google don't keep the tooling up to date to make it testable. I will wait and see if the plugin gets an update and if not just give up on supporting this.

Comment: Same problem here and testing on physical device makes a lot of problems :/

Comment: @JamieH Jetbrains updated their Google Assistant Plugin on February 7th, 2024. See the answer below for a link (or you know, google it!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Android studio and you can find a Google Assistant plugin compatible with your latest Android studio. if not available you can install from -> [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16739-google-assistant/versions/stable).

Comment: Thank you!  The Jetbrains Google Assistant Plugin was not updated to be compatible with Android Studio (Hedgehog) when I asked the question.  It's nice to see they released a compatible version--That should make my testing process a lot faster!